# Speedometer Not Working

Tags: hyundai, speedometer, santa-fe

I have a 3.3l 2008 Santa Fe. My speedometer stopped working recently, although it comes back to life in short, random periods. Also, the gas gauge goes up and down slightly (usually when I’m accelerating). Cruise control still works and there’s no check engine light, so I don’t think it’s the Vehicle Speed Sensor. Any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a loose connector to the dash - check and make sure they are secure.